# Fancybox opening image in new page

Tags: fancybox

I've checked through all the questions and answers on here... still can't figure it out..

I followed directions on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Suxu_nG7R1M

The test page where I'm trying to get this fancybox to work is http://www.beautybycrystalanne.com/118vpb.html

there's only one picture. when I click it, a regular jpeg page opens with it.

Suggestions? Please?!?

Comment: You are getting a js error because this line `$(".fancybox").fancybox().` .... there is an extra dot after the parenthesis of the fancybox method.

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a link for a fancybox popup you need to use the class or id assigned with the fancybox function.

**1) Install JQuery and then reference it in the HEAD section of your website** (alternatively reference it from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

**2) Add Fancybox by downloading it and referencing it in the HEAD section of your website.** (download fancybox here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license)

**3) Create link elements whose href attributes will contain the path of the element you wish to open within the fancyBox.**

Then you can call the fancybox jquery function by including this on the page containing the link element mentioned above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit of the instructions in the link?  We're trying to prevent linkrot in general.